# Is there any way to use/configure/manage VDP after flash technology has been phased out?

Tags: backup, virtual-machines, vmware-vcenter, flash

I have two VDP (probably latest version) deployed on the vCenter 6.5 with about 60 virtual machines backup.
Currently VDP plugin is not visible in the HTML vCenter interface and I cannot access any VDP for configuration or to restore virtual machines.

I saw in the vCenter "Recent tasks" in the HTML interface that VDP is probably still fully functional bacause backups are still running in the evening.

Is there any way/workaround for managing/configurig/restoring virtual machines from VDP after flash technology has been phased out?

Comment: Please don't add a signature block to your posts; you can put all the information you want to publish about yourself in your profile, and the user card underneath each post allows everyone who wants to find out more about you to click on that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/kvvvkr/adobe_flash_eol_workaround/

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/78589

Flash already running in my browsers

Cheers
Artur